# Code chef | bench press problem - I took this problem and solved it partially, with the sample test-cases. Can you kindly point out what I have missed

Tags: python, testing

[image: Problem Description]

[image: input AND testCases]

Python3 Code:

```
testCases = int(input())
for i in range(testCases):
    line1 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    weights = [int(y) for y in input().split()]
    numberOfWeights,requiredWeight,rodWeight = line1[0],line1[1],line1[2]
    if (requiredWeight <= rodWeight):
        print("YES")
        continue
    lookupWeights = list()
    for j in range(numberOfWeights):
        if (requiredWeight <= rodWeight):
            break
        if(weights[j] in  lookupWeights):
            rodWeight += (2*weights[j])
            lookupWeights.remove(weights[j])
        else:
            lookupWeights.append(weights[j])
    if (requiredWeight <= rodWeight):
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

I have tried many test cases and it still seems to be working fine, but was not accepted for submission. Now I know the code is not efficient. All I require is a sample test case to break this code/logic.

Sample test Case 1:

```
3
2 5 10 
2 2
7 100 50
100 10 10 10 10 10 90 
6 100 40 
10 10 10 10 10 10

Output: 
YES
NO
YES

TEST CASE 2:

1
8 100 40
10 20 10 25 30 40 30 50

Output:
YES
```

Comment: Do you know if you fail because of time or because of wrong answer?

Comment: I mean, this _will_ fail on time for some test cases.

Comment: This one failed on both time and wrong answer.So there were 2 hidden cases The time limit was 0.5 seconds and it failed at 0.17 seconds